# How Do i return different generes in Salesforce

Tags: soql

How do i go about an SOQL Query where i want the results to be Horror or Mystery I have a dummy Object Created and I want to return the Results to display any of those generes as reults.

The SOQL I wrote is Looking Like this : `Select id, Genere__c from Movie__c where Genere__c LIKE '%Horror%' AND '%Mystery%'`, Could this be right if i present it this way?

Does not return the data requested.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer

```
Select id, Movie_Name__c,Genre__c from Movie__c where Genre__c LIKE '%Mystery%' OR Genre__c LIKE '%Horror%'
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you need `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

`Select id, Genere__c from Movie__c where Genere__c = 'Horror' OR  Genere__c = 'Mystery'`. You use `OR` because either of this values satisfy you requirements